# WiFi driver suddenly stops working, reinstalling does nothing

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, drivers, repair

The problems started last week when I booted up my laptop. I noticed when I logged in a connection symbol with an (X) on it. Hovering over it says `Not connected - No connections are avaliable`. I run network diagnostics but all it says is `Ethernet cable is not plugged in or it may be broken`. I really don't want to use an ethernet cable to use the internet because im all around the house. And the router is in a tight space too.

**What I have Tried**

I Uninstalled the drivers from ASUS' setup program from control panel, then reinstalling it. Still nothing happens.

I uninstall the wifi driver from `devmgmt.msc` and reinstall the wifi driver, but that dosen't work either.

**What I** *don't* **Want to do:**

1)Go to a repair shop up the road and pay for repairs

2)Buy a new laptop or buy a dongle (I mean another, the one I use for my raspberry pi isn't being picked up from windows)

Comment: Did you checked whether Wireless adapter is disabled or not in Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Internet Connections ?

Comment: Yes, The Wireless adapter isn't there.

Comment: That's the problem.

Comment: I tried devmgmt.msc just now and `network controller` was listed in other devices. Plus it had a ! on it. Attempting to update causes it to say `Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless network adapter - Windows encountered a problem installing software for your device` and says at the bottom `This operation requires an interactive window station`

Answer (score 0):

if you setup the driver and you are sure about it, then your problem from "network controller driver" uninstall the driver then use [driver booster](http://www.iobit.com/driver-booster.php) it's free app to find & setup the driver, make a restart and that's it :)

Comment: It dosen't solve the issue of my internet problem. This is because driver booster requires an internet connection to function correctly.